# operation must use on updateable query

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, gridview

```
<asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" DataKeyNames="Kimlik" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black">
      <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Kimlik" HeaderText="Kimlik" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Kimlik" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="uye_ad" HeaderText="uye_ad" SortExpression="uye_ad" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="uye_soyad" HeaderText="uye_soyad" SortExpression="uye_soyad" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="kadi" HeaderText="kadi" SortExpression="kadi" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="sifre" HeaderText="sifre" SortExpression="sifre" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="mail" HeaderText="mail" SortExpression="mail" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="tc" HeaderText="tc" SortExpression="tc" />
          <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
      </Columns>
      <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      <RowStyle BackColor="White" Width="200px" />
      <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" CssClass="&lt;br/&gt;" />
      <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
      <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
      <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
  </asp:GridView>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [uyeler] WHERE [Kimlik] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [uyeler] ([Kimlik], [uye_ad], [uye_soyad], [kadi], [sifre], [mail], [tc]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [uyeler] WHERE ([mail] = ?)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [uyeler] SET [uye_ad] = ?, [uye_soyad] = ?, [kadi] = ?, [sifre] = ?, [mail] = ?, [tc] = ? WHERE [Kimlik] = ?">
      <DeleteParameters>
          <asp:Parameter Name="Kimlik" Type="Int32" />
      </DeleteParameters>
      <InsertParameters>
          <asp:Parameter Name="Kimlik" Type="Int32" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="uye_ad" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="uye_soyad" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="kadi" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="sifre" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="mail" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="tc" Type="String" />
      </InsertParameters>
      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:SessionParameter Name="mail" SessionField="mail" Type="String" />
      </SelectParameters>
      <UpdateParameters>
          <asp:Parameter Name="uye_ad" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="uye_soyad" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="kadi" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="sifre" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="mail" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="tc" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="Kimlik" Type="Int32" />
      </UpdateParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:View>
```

I'm developing a project with asp.net c #. I used the GridView object in my web pages. but update, delete, insert operations in the 'must-user operation on Updateable query' I get an error. I used the access the database. I gave all the powers of puberty folder database. but the problem still continues. try, catch, finally I used the tags error still continues. please help me.!

Here's the

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
 DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [uyeler] 
                WHERE [Kimlik] = ?" 
 InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [uyeler] 
               ([Kimlik], [uye_ad], [uye_soyad], [kadi], [sifre], [mail], [tc]) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
 ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
 SelectCommand="
     SELECT * FROM [uyeler] 
     WHERE ([mail] = ?)" 
UpdateCommand="
     UPDATE [uyeler] 
     SET [uye_ad] = ?, [uye_soyad] = ?, [kadi] = ?, [sifre] = ?, [mail] = ?, [tc] = ? 
     WHERE [Kimlik] = ?
">
```

Comment: The error says that the *query* is not update-able, it is not talking about permissions or anything else.  You did share the query or how you try to update it.

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [uyeler] WHERE [Kimlik] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [uyeler] ([Kimlik], [uye_ad], [uye_soyad], [kadi], [sifre], [mail], [tc]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [uyeler] WHERE ([mail] = ?)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [uyeler] SET [uye_ad] = ?, [uye_soyad] = ?, [kadi] = ?, [sifre] = ?, [mail] = ?, [tc] = ? WHERE [Kimlik] = ?">

Comment: <UpdateParameters><asp:Parameter Name="uye_ad" Type="String" /><asp:Parameter Name="uye_soyad" Type="String" /><asp:Parameter Name="kadi" Type="String" /><asp:Parameter Name="sifre" Type="String" /><asp:Parameter Name="mail" Type="String" />
                                                          <asp:Parameter Name="tc" Type="String" />
                                                          <asp:Parameter Name="Kimlik" Type="Int32" />
                                                      </UpdateParameters>

Comment: No code. I established direct contact with the GridView, I wrote all the code as above. I created everything through the GridView object

Comment: you can't edit your question?

Comment: I want to access the current data in the database on the website using the GridView. I gave exactly the authority to access the folder as my database. but I get this error. operation must use an Updateable query. this problem. what should I do.

Comment: Can you read your code? Did you look at the snippet you've posted? Please don't add more work for us than really necessary.

Comment: No. I used this code. localhost web page works. but threw ftp it is not working.

Comment: Is `Kimlik` a view / query instead of a table? If it's a table does it have a primary key defined?

Comment: if localhost works then its definitiley a permission issue. read this. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/74/solving-the-operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-error

Comment: I read the article, but I made what is written here.It is not

Comment: Is Kimlik a view / query instead of a table? If it's a table does it have a primary key defined?